# Where should I ask about which platform to use for an embedded controller application?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I tried posting this on Stack Overflow and was told hardware questions are not allowed (yet, most Arduino hits on Stack Exchange are at Stack Overflow). Is there a site where I can ask this question?

> I need help choosing hardware, language, and IDE for an application that requires more computing power than an Arduino provides. Because of the nature of the team, it would be great if it were as easy to use as Arduino.
>
> Essential hardware features are:
>
> - interrupts, UART, SPI, and about 10 GPIO.
>
> The code will use:
>
> - signed 32-bit numbers but it does not require floating-point support.
> - Probably not more than 1000 lines of code if in C.
> - The application is a high-resolution multi-channel PID controller with a simple command parser so it can be controlled by text commands via the UART.
> - We prefer a bare-metal implementation.
> - RTOS is not required.
> - The board should be small and < $20 in quantities of 100. Open source is always better.
> - Low power is not important.
> - It should be programmable through the UART or USB.
>
> So what are some good options to look at? There are no language restrictions. C might work but we are open to other options, for example MicroPython or eLua.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Unfortunately these are closely coupled issues in embedded systems. It turns out there is an r/embedded subreddit and over there I am getting lots of good guidance.

Comment: @gnat this question would not be on topic on any of the sites with sections there.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to ask different questions on at least two sites:

- For hardware recommendations there is the [Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://harwarerecs.stackexchange.com)
- For software (language and IDE) recommendations there is the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://harwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

If you decide to ask a question on either, or both, then be sure to follow their asking guidelines, which are strict.

Comment: Thanks for this response. After a few weeks on the SE sites I am seeing that the compartmentalization and the strict rule-enforcement make systems-level questions difficult. However I have enjoyed some of the threads in physics, EE and chemistry.